# Add an Object key and value to an exsiting object

Tags: forloop, array

I am looping over an array of objects and trying to add a new Key and Value.

I keep getting a host of errors so was hoping someone could help a little with formatting this loop.

```
{{ set = transforms: [{ width: 2000, height: 1333 }] }}

{%- set transforms_WEBP = transforms -%}
{%- set transforms_JPG = transforms|default([]) -%}

{% for i in transforms_WEBP %}
  {{ transforms_WEBP[loop.index0]|merge({format: 'webp'}) }}
{% endfor %}

{% set transforms = transforms_WEBP|merge(transforms_JPG) %}
```

I keep getting ARRAY to String conversion but I am missing where I am going wrong.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors in your code. First,

`{{ set = transforms: [{ width: 2000, height: 1333 }] }}`

Should be:

`{% set transforms = [{ width: 2000, height: 1333 }] %}`

And inside you for loop, this:

`{{ transforms_WEBP[loop.index0]|merge({format: 'webp'}) }}`

Should be something more like this:

`{% set transforms_WEBP = transforms_WEBP[loop.index0]|merge({format: 'webp'}) %}`

**HOWEVER...**

That's also not going to work, because you can't directly set the index value of a twig array like that, the way you can in PHP.

What I suggest you do is re-factor your code to something a little closer to this:

```
    {% set transforms = [
        { width: 2000, height: 1333 },
        { width: 1000, height: 667 },
    ] %}

    {% for i in transforms %}           
        {% set i = i|merge({format: 'webp'}) %}
        {% set transforms = transforms|merge([i]) %}
    {% endfor %}
```

This will result in a `transforms` variable that looks like this:

```
[
    0 => [
        'width' => 2000
        'height' => 1333
    ]
    1 => [
        'width' => 1000
        'height' => 667
    ]
    2 => [
        'width' => 2000
        'height' => 1333
        'format' => 'webp'
    ]
    3 => [
        'width' => 1000
        'height' => 667
        'format' => 'webp'
    ]
]
```